# Automated Azure Password change

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-shell

I'm searching for a way to change my (Login-) Password in Azure via PowerShell.
I have only access to my own Account and can't use any Principals or Azure Active Directory because of missing rights.

Because I'm able to change the Password manually via the Azure Portal over Profile and change Password, I'm sure there has to be a way over PowerShell to automate this process.

I already tried:

```
MSOnlineExtended\Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $user -NewPassword $pwd -ForceChange
```

but this is not working because of missing rights.

Answer (score 1):

All the Azure PowerShell commands I am aware of, assume you have a role in Azure AD that allows management of users, I don't believe there is a way to just reset your own password in this manner. I don't believe the APIs to do this are exposed.